# Join three tables with where clause using group by

Tags: sql, join

I have three table as ->

- `Subjects` with the columns `sub_id`, `sub_code`, `branch id`
- `Papers` with the columns `paper_id`, `sub_code`, `paper_title`
- `Branch` with `branch_id`, `branch_title`

I want  to get result as:

```
 paper_id  paper_link branch_title
```

I have run the following query

```
SELECT papers.paper_id, papers.paper_title,papers.paper_link,brnches.branch_title 
FROM papers 
JOIN subjects ON papers.sub_code   =  subjects.sub_code 
JOIN brnches ON brnches.branch_id  =  subjects.brnch_id
WHERE paper_title LIKE '%$keyoword%'
```

but does not get any results

Comment: What do you get if you run the query without the where clause?

Comment: Nothing matches the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: i get result but not that is excepted

Comment: Explain why it isn’t the expected result? Does all papers have a subject, does all subjects have a branch? Maybe you need another type of JOIN between some of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump your $keyword value and check that it is correct. 
If correct, check that the value exists in the papers.paper_title column. 
If it does, try performing FULL OUTER JOINs rather than JOINs.

Hope this helps.

Also I `noticed` that your requirements state "paper_id,sub_code and paper _title", but your SELECT statement includes "paper_link".